# Facebook event comment.create not firing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I'm using the Facebook "like" button and [subscribing to two events](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/):

> **edge.create** - when the user clicks the "Like" button
>
> **comment.create** - when the user then types a comment in the flyout
>   window that appears

The edge.create event is firing, but comment.create doesn't seem to happen. Here's the code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '1111111111111', // App ID
        channelUrl : '//www.xxx.com/channel.php', // Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
        function(response) {
            // user clicked facebook "like" button
            alert("like");
        }
    );

    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create',
        function(response) {
            // user added comment to facebook like
            alert("comment");
        }
    );
};
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks. -E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that event is fired for the Like button's 'add a comment' popup; it's only documented as working with the Comments Plugin itself

Comment: Ah. That's a shame. Can anyone confirm? Do you know if there is an event for when someone adds a comment to a "like"?

Comment: I don't think so; it sounds reasonable to me that it would, but i dont't think it's ever worked that way and it's not documented that way either